# How to keep a image in s3 bucket without changing its key

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, multer-s3

I am trying to make a profile pic editor from which we can upload a image directly to s3 bucket and storing the address in mongodb database using multer

But problem is whenever I keep the key of image same. For ex ("profile-image")the picture gets uploaded but does not changes instantly but it changes after some time //5-10 mins later

But when I keep key changing for ex with `${Date.now()}+profile-avatar`
Then profile pic changes instantly

Can someone pls help out wheater there is mistake in my code or I have to change my aws s3 bucket settings
I am very new to aws s3.

Comment: Are you using CloudFront? If so, sounds like you need to do cache invalidation

Comment: This is not a mongodb question.

Comment: A good way to do "cache busting" is to add a parameter to the URL (eg `image.jpg/?version=2`). Amazon S3 will not interpret the parameter, but it will likely cause the cache to be refreshed. This is a good way to investigate what might be happening.